# A strange issue with container and child form? Please guide me

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

In a container form I have menu and buttons to open ther forms.

[image]

Here I am facing a problem when I open any form these buttns and lables come over newly opened form.

[image]

Please guide me how I can manage this issue ? I want to open a new form and keep these container form's controls in back ground of it.

thanks for guiding and helping me.